# Odoo and Nodejs(Express application) integration

Tags: node.js, postgresql, odoo

I'm working on a project for a tutoring institute where we have an existing Odoo application managing our data. We now need to create a web application using React that provides two interfaces: one for instructors and one for students. Each interface should display a list of appointments, and users should be able to schedule new appointments.

Here's where I need guidance:

Backend Choices:

We are considering two backend options:
Using the Odoo REST API.
Using Node.js with Express.js to create a custom backend.
Odoo REST API:

We are aware of the Odoo REST API's capabilities, but we are concerned about the customization complexity. None of our team members have prior experience with Odoo.
Node.js with Express.js:

Is it possible to create an Express.js backend that connects with our Odoo application?
and how will services like authentication be implemented?
We want to ensure that when instructors teach new lessons, the Odoo database is updated to reflect changes in their salary.
Could someone provide insights, guidance, or a code example on how to achieve this integration with an Express.js application? Any advice or experiences you can share would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I haven't tried anything yet I/m still trying to figure out which approach is more effictive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest you to read the documentation about odoo external api here :

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/external_api.html

you can implement this with your express server and as for the authentication you can store a jwt token and handle it with your express server as well

i hope it is helpful and if you have any questions i am here to help

Comment: Hi Amin,
Yes I'm aware of the External API But the thing that I'm trying is to connect to the db directly without the xmlrpc so basically run normal SQL queries on the db.
Is that considered a bad practice and I should only use xmlrpc to interact with the db??
I used xmlrpc for authentication and it worked I managed to retrieve the user information and used JWT in my express app.
Thank you for your help

Comment: hi there well odoo does some other computing and logic under the hood when data is changed.
depending on apps you use this may defer and if you have enough knowledge about the app behavior it is ok.
but me personally won't do direct queries and use xmlrpc.

Comment: Thank you, It turns out that accessing the database directly is not possible because the ORM handles the access rights, and the sanity checks.

Comment: your welcome
good to hear your problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have some experiences in Node.js wit Express.js and Odoo Rest API too.
Talking about this, first you can connect to the Odoo app using various libs available for Odoo integration such as  `node-odoo or xmlrpc`.
If then you can make operation like CRUD operation on Odoo models.

And next is integrating the Express.js with Odoo.
After the connection is established, you can use the lib to perform operations like fetching appointment data, creating new appointments, updating salaries etc.

To interact with the Odoo app's data you can use library's methods like `search, read, create, update, delete`.

You can implement authentication using middleware like JWT or session-based authentication.

Comment: Hi David, It's very nice to meet you too.
I would love to hear more about your opinion about  the project I'm working on,
We should connect on linkedin.
You can find me here:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ali-omarr/

Comment: Thanks for your invitation, starrynightskyhoney@gmail.com, please contact me to this.